# How to make PHP function run only after triggered first time?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Please tell me, how could I make a PHP function run only once in this setting (in CodeIgniter):

When a link on a page is clicked it goes to `href="http://foo.com/func/id/"`. Based on the `id` url segment, the `func` segment runs a function which decides where to redirect the user who clicked the link.

What I'd like to achieve is this:

```
function func($id)
{
if ("first time link($id) is clicked by unique user") {
// Redirect based on $id
} else {
// Redirect to homepage
} }
```

Basically, each click on the same link after the first click will trigger the `else` case.
Links can have any IDs or classes if needed.

I'd like this code to stay true for clicked links at least until current page is closed, but perhaps lengthen it to browser session or even based on a timer if possible - perhaps a PHP session..?

Comment: Perhaps a php session. Or maybe some javascript to react onclick and change the link to add a parameter?

Comment: If you're trying to make it respond to only the first click across all users, then the only healthy way to store this is via the database. If you want it to be the first time it's clicked by current user only, then a $_SESSION variable will do fine.

Comment: Well you have to know what you want -> define what "first" means: First time EVER SOMEONE clicks the link, first time per person someone clicks the link. Then you have to define what a person is: identified by id, by session, by userid (registring), by time, by cookie.... it really depends on what you understand as "first"

Comment: clicking the link does a GET request. [Get requests should be idempotent and safe](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), so it violates the semantics of HTTP to have something else happen on the second click

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to keep state (still, HTTP is stateless).

You must keep a flag server side, like a database record, a file or even an in-memory semaphore.

I didn't understand if the desired behavior is "cross" or single user.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps,

```
function func($id)
{
    if (@$_SESSION['linkClicked']) {
        // Redirect to homepage
    } else {
        $_SESSION['linkClicked'] = true;
        // Redirect based on $id
    } 
}
```

Comment: Although this would work, I would use `isset('linkClicked',$_SESSION) AND $_SESSION['linkClicked']` instead of using the `@` silencer. That's just me, though.

Comment: This won't work if he is tracking multiple links across his site.

Comment: @SolracRagnarockradio I agree. My code snippet is to get Alex started and explore further based on his requirement.

Comment: No, I'm intending to track only clicks per uniquely loaded page per unique user, and as long as that page is open. @sudipto So your code applies on a per page basis? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has 2 temp storages out-of-the-box for you:

```
$_COOKIE
$_SESSION
```

Depending on how much data you will store these can be useful/useless to you. If the data you will store is too big (e, 200 links references) then you might be better off storing these in a file and linking them through the user session id or in a SQL table.

**PHP by itself has no way of telling who's clicking what as it is serverside programing.** So please consider this:

```
function func($Link_id){

  if (in_array($Link_id, $_SESSION['my_links'])){
    $_SESSION['my_links'][]=$Link_id;
    // Redirect to homepage
  } else {
    // Redirect based on $id
  }

}
```

Comment: Will a session, in this case, also store a cookie? Thanks.

Comment: Session will store the data on PHP's session handler which is a file in your OS.
If you will to save data on a cookie you have to use the global $_COOKIE instead but is safer to use $_SESSION as it's easier to modify a cookie clientside.